# When to use error, mistake?

Tags: grammaticality

One person said, "he made a silly error". Is it appropriate to say silly error rather than saying silly mistake?

Comment: Have you looked up both words in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Error and mistake are both fine in this context. Error is just slightly more formal.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140028)

Comment: @mdewey I think this is a quite adequate answer to this question. Indeed I have upvoted it.